# BeautifulSoup doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with BeautifulSoup. I'm trying to extract data for each table from this website: http://www.fantagazzetta.com/voti-serie-a/2016-17/6

However BeautifulSoup skips many rows of code, this is my python script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get('http://www.fantagazzetta.com/voti-serie-a/2016-17/4')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'row no-gutter tbvoti'})
print(data)
```

my output is just this:

```
<div class="row no-gutter tbvoti" data-team="1" id="Ata"></div>
```

How can I extract the code inside each table? 
Thanks and sorry for my english

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhjji.png)

I mean it skips the code between ::before and ::after and i wanna extract it.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over the list `find_all` returns:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get('http://www.fantagazzetta.com/voti-serie-a/2016-17/4')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'row no-gutter tbvoti'})

print(' '.join([str(part) for part in data]))
```

Comment: thank for the answer but the problem is not that :), i have uploaded a picture  for making it clear